# Is $2^{125} \bmod 257$ $=225$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I did how $256=-1$ mod $257$ and $2^8=256$ then $(2^8)^{15}=-1 $ mod $257$ and i conclude that $2^{125} \bmod 257 = 225$

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: +1 Nice analysis, you nailed it.  Further, it seems clear that your analysis, which focused on the relationship between $2^8$ and $(257)$ represents the **intent** of the problem composer.

Comment: Who me? ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @SomeGuy I don't know who upvoted your comment.  I was responding to the original poster, whose query I upvoted.